# Why does 'svn update' attempt to merge on Ctrl-C?

Tags: svn

As per the log below, I tried to do `svn update`, got a conflict, `ctrl-C`d out of it, then tried to do it again. No attempt at conflict resolution on the second run, text to be merged automatically inserted into the source. Why?

```
$ svn update

Summary of conflicts:
  Text conflicts: 1
Conflict discovered in file 'myFileName'.
Select: (p) postpone, (df) show diff, (e) edit file, (m) merge,
        (mc) my side of conflict, (tc) their side of conflict,
        (s) show all options: s 

  (e)  - change merged file in an editor  [edit]
  (df) - show all changes made to merged file
  (r)  - accept merged version of file  [working]

  (dc) - show all conflicts (ignoring merged version)
  (mc) - accept my version for all conflicts (same)  [mine-conflict]
  (tc) - accept their version for all conflicts (same)  [theirs-conflict]

  (mf) - accept my version of entire file (even non-conflicts)  [mine-full]
  (tf) - accept their version of entire file (same)  [theirs-full]

  (m)  - use merge tool to resolve conflict
  (l)  - launch external merge tool to resolve conflict  [launch]
  (i)  - use built-in merge tool to resolve conflict
  (p)  - mark the conflict to be resolved later  [postpone]
  (q)  - postpone all remaining conflicts
  (s)  - show this list (also 'h', '?')
Words in square brackets are the corresponding --accept option arguments.

Select: (p) postpone, (df) show diff, (e) edit file, (m) merge,
        (mc) my side of conflict, (tc) their side of conflict,
        (s) show all options: ^Csvn: E155027: Unable to resolve conflicts on 'myFileName'
svn: E200015: The operation was interrupted

$ svn update
Updating '.':
At revision 95171.
```

Answer (score 0):

Conflicts in SVN happends when you work in an outdated version of the file, maybe someone else work in the same file, commit the changes and when you try to update there was a conflict.
If your SVN client has a tool to merge the files, you can manually solve the conflict, if it doesn't, you can download the whole proyect in other folder and merge the files in the new project.

Comment: So, what's the answer? :-)